# How to I can use landscape mode it should cutoff to max phone width

Tags: android, landscape

How to I can use landscape mode it should cutoff to max phone width like image below:
https://imgur.com/a/AIzqtG4

I expecting same image, portrait mode inside landscape mode for tablet or any large device. Please check the image above

Thank every body very much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.